# What is Christianity's take on Kabbalah?

Tags: mysticism, gnosticism

I like to research religions and recently I started studying Kabbalah, the Jewish mysticism.

They claim that they've unlocked the key to the "upper worlds" and a few more claims such as there's no satan, no free will, no sin etc. even though some of their teachings makes sense yet the structure of their idea is... questionable!

What is Christianity's take on Kabbalah?

Comment: Whose 'take' are you interested in ? I think the question needs to be scoped.

Comment: @NigelJ Christians in general.

Comment: _Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed. They must be edited to ask for one perspective, or to explicitly ask for an overview of all Christian positions._ [See the Tour and the Help, below, bottom left.]

Comment: @NigelJ "explicitly ask for an overview of all Christian positions" that's my question. my eye hurts reading the font you typed!

Comment: I used italic for emphasis. On a PC, Control and the plus key allow you to zoom in and enlarge the screen.

Comment: @NigelJ This site font needs changing, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many people who self-identify as Christians, who are also 'into' Kabbalah'. There are probably many more who have never even heard of Kabbalah, and a good many more still who would express alarm at the very idea of any Christian getting involved in Kabbalah. That is why such a broad-ranging questions needs to be narrowed down (scoped) to a specific group within Christianity.

My answer is that of a Christian who would be alarmed at a Christian trying to mix Kabbalah up with Christianity. First, a bit of background about the origins of Kabbalah is helpful.

Kabbalah only developed between the 6th and 13th centuries A.D. among the Jews in Babylonia, Italy, Provence, and Spain. This means that it never existed in the time of Jesus. The word “Kabbalah” means "to receive" and it claims that revelations from God were received by Jews and passed to succeeding generations through oral tradition. The word was first used by mainstream Judaism but later came to refer to those who believed that only a select few were given secret knowledge from God as to the "true" meaning of Scriptures. Kabbalah uses occult practices, which, in itself, goes against the scriptures God gave to the Jews, way back in the time of Moses.

Kabbalah is similar to Greek Gnosticism. Both groups believed that only a select few were given deeper understanding or knowledge. But Kabbalah teaches that “emanations” from God did the work of creation, denying that creation was a creative act directly from God. This, again, goes against the scriptures given to Moses. It claims that God created a lesser god, which then created an even lesser god, and this kept happening until the end result was angels. Kabbalah is big on angels but Christians are warned in the Bible not to go down that road of angel adoration - Colossians 2:18.

Ideas about 'a demi-urge' or 'Sefirot' are all linked. In a 1548 Postel the Sefirot world is shown in the form of a menorah (a 7-branched candlestick). The Sefirot are the 10 divine emanations through which adherents to this mystical tradition believe the finite universe and its creatures are sustained. The Bible holy texts do not support any of that, and the New Testament in particular openly condemned such gnostic, mystical ideas that were trying to infiltrate the new Christian church

Kabbalah even has a pantheistic characteristic. Pantheism is the idea that God and his creation are one. This is not what God has told us in the Bible, nor did Jesus teach that. Finally, it denies the deity of Christ and the necessity of faith in him as the only means of salvation - this is the core teaching of Christianity.

See the link below for the source and more links.
http://www.gotquestions.org/Kabbalah.html

Comment: Kabbalah, in its various forms, has been around much longer than 1,500 years.  Some believe at least since about 200 years prior to Christ's birth, which idea points back to the beginnings of Israel, and even to the Garden. https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380666/jewish/Overview.htm  For Christians, we believe all was done by Jesus in the open and apostles given full knowledge without any hidden instruction or oral knowledge, as in contend for the faith once delivered (as written).